# What will happen if lambda timeout while processing a batch of messages from event source mapping from Kafka?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, serverless

We're having an aws lambda which triggered by Self-managed Kafka via event source mapping. I want to know what will happened in this case:
Let say I have 20 messages returned from lambda's events.
I finished to process 10 items and the lambda timeout.

What will happen with the remaining 10 items which is processing?
Will other lambdas fetch them from kafka and process or they will be lost?
And in case if they're lost, is there any way to handle the lost messages properly?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: My expectation would be that a retry of all 20 messages will happen since the lambda has not returned / cannot return any kind of confirmation of any processing. "If your function returns an error for any of the messages in a batch, Lambda retries the whole batch of messages until processing succeeds or the messages expire." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/kafka-smaa.html

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes, it will retry the whole batch when error. But in this case, the lambda suddenly terminated when timed out so I'm not sure if it will retry the batch again

Comment: A timeout is identical to an error in terms of the lambda not giving any kind of success feedback and being retried.

Comment: I see your point, but in case of time out, the lambda was terminated. So it cannot retry the batch operation. You think that another lambda will do it ?

Comment: Exact same thing as any normal error: the same lambda execution environment or maybe another one will get the batch again, you can't know for certain and neither must it matter.

Answer (score 0):

If the lambda doesn't commit the Kafka offsets before it times out, then you should expect any future event to repeat consumption from the same topic position until either offsets are committed for those records, or they are removed due to topic retention policies, and the consumer moves on.

Same answer applies to any Kafka consumer poll processing loop.

Comment: Hey! I think it is not exactly what the author was asking. AWS provides a tool for reporting batch failures for DynamoDB streams for [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html#services-ddb-batchfailurereporting). So Lambda function does not need to re-consume the entire batch, if it fails in the middle of that batch, all processed record offsets will be committed. So the question is - maybe something like that exists when the event source is MSK? I could not find anything in AWS documentation related to that

Comment: Kafka consumers only auto commit offsets if you tell it to. MSK isn't responsible for that, your consumer code is. Lambda is just a wrapper around Kafka consumer API

Comment: If to use MSK as an **event source** - it encapsulates a lot of behavior and sets limits for the Consumer of what it can or cannot do. I don't think one can commit an offset **programmatically**, It is committed implicitly if Lambda does not return an error after fetching a record or set of records (batch). So if one configures Lambda to consume a batch and managed to process N out of X records and Lambda returns an Error there is no way to tell commit N offset, you will be forced to re-consume the entire batch. The only approach to handle that is to set the batch size to 1

Comment: You could use `consumer.commit()` calls. If lamdba does that on its own, that'll just override what the code does. Doesn't mean you "cant" do it, just that the next poll/restart will use an offset other than what is expected